# Creating JSon in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am very new to ASP.net . How could I create the following JSON object in c#

```
{"total":2,"rows":[{"productid":"1","attr":{"size":"10dc","color":"red&yellow"},
                    {"productid":"2","attr":{"size":"102dc","color":"green&white"}
```

My ultimate aim is to send this JSON Object to client side data gird for data binding.The grid is expecting the data in this format

Comment: please read this article http://simpledotnetsolutions.wordpress.com/2012/11/25/jstree-few-examples-with-asp-netc/
and 
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Send-and-Receive-JSON-objects-to-Web-Service-Methods-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) is an easy way to do this, to create the output in your example, define your class structure:

```
public class DefaultObject
{
    public int total;
    public List<Row> rows;
}
public class Row {
    public string productid;
    public Attribute attr;

}

public class Attribute {
    public string size;
    public string color;
}
```

Then create an instance and serialize it:

```
List<Row> Rows = new List<Row>();
Rows.Add(new Row() { productid="1", attr = new Attribute() { color = "red&yellow", size = "10dc"}});
Rows.Add(new Row() { productid="2", attr = new Attribute() { color = "green&white", size = "102dc"}});
DefaultObject obj = new DefaultObject { total = 2, rows = Rows};

Debug.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
```